How can I call a closure for the correct subview?
I have a closure in a section provider in a diffable data source initializer where I am setting the variable checkCellView from inside the closure. When I call the closure from switchCheckSelectionFunc() in CheckCellView the wrong cell ends up getting selected. How can I fix this?
class QuestionnaireViewController: UIViewController { 

    var checkCellView: CheckCellView? {
        didSet {
            if checkCellView != nil {
                print("type of closure,", type(of: checkCellView!.switchCheckSelection))
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    }

    func configureDataSource() {
        dataSource = CustomTableViewDiffableDataSource(tableView: tableView, cellProvider: { [self] tableView, indexPath, formItem in
            
            // print("section,", indexPath.section)
            
            self.checkCellView?.switchCheckSelection = { checkIsSelected in
                if checkIsSelected {
                    checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-selected")!
                } else {
                    checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                }
            }
            
            switch formItem {
            case .name(let name):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PatientInfoCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! PatientInfoCell
                cell.configure(title: "First Name")
                return cell
            case .lastName(let lastName):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PatientInfoCell.reuseID) as! PatientInfoCell
                cell.configure(title: "Last Name")
                return cell
            case .age(let age):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PatientInfoCell.reuseID) as! PatientInfoCell
                cell.configure(title: "Age")
                return cell
            case .gender(let gender):
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GenderCell.reuseID) as! GenderCell
                cell.titleView.text = "Gender"
                cell.femaleIcon.image = UIImage(named: "female-icon-deselected")!
                cell.switchFemaleIconTapped = { isSelected in
                    if isSelected {
                        cell.femaleIcon.image = UIImage(named: "female-icon-selected")!
                    } else {
                        cell.femaleIcon.image = UIImage(named: "female-icon-deselected")!
                    }
                }
                cell.maleIcon.image = UIImage(named: "male-icon-deselected")!
                cell.switchMaleIconTapped = {
                    if $0 {
                        cell.maleIcon.image = UIImage(named: "male-icon-selected")!
                    } else {
                        cell.maleIcon.image = UIImage(named: "male-icon-deselected")!
                    }
                }
                return cell
            case .indwellingCardiacDeviceOrProsthesis(let bool):
                checkCellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckCellView.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? CheckCellView
                checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                
                checkCellView?.switchCheckSelection = { checkIsSelected in
                    if checkIsSelected {
                        checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-selected")!
                    } else {
                        checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                    }
                }
                
                return checkCellView
            case .predisposingHeartCondition(let bool):
                checkCellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckCellView.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? CheckCellView
                checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                return checkCellView
            case .intravenousDrugUse(let bool):
                checkCellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckCellView.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? CheckCellView
                checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                return checkCellView
            case .cardiacStructuralDisorder(let bool):
                checkCellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckCellView.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? CheckCellView
                checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                return checkCellView
            case .diabetic(let bool):
                checkCellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckCellView.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? CheckCellView
                checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
                return checkCellView
            }
        })
    }

}

class CheckCellView: UITableViewCell {
    
    var titleView: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var checkImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    static var reuseID = "check-cell-reuseID"
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUp()
    }
    
    var switchCheckSelection: ((_ isSelected: Bool) -> Void)?
    var checkIsSelected: Bool = false
    
    func setUp() {
        
        checkImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(switchCheckSelectionFunc)))
        checkImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            titleView,
            checkImageView
        ])
        
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func switchCheckSelectionFunc() {
        checkIsSelected.toggle()
        switchCheckSelection?(checkIsSelected)
    }
    
    func applySnapshot() {
                
        guard case let .questionnaireData(formData) = data,
              let formData = formData else {
            return
        }
        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, FormItem>()
        
        snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)
                
        snapshot.appendItems(formData.patientInfoData, toSection: .patientInformation)
        
        snapshot.appendItems(formData.checkAllThatApplyData, toSection: .checkAllThatApply)
        
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }

}



Where do you actually call the closure?  You can't have single property that is holding a reference to a cell and use that because it will hold the reference to the last cell that was dequeue and that could be any cell

I am calling the closure in the switchCheckSelectionFunc() function. Ah okay got it I thought that the variable holds a unique reference to each cell.

When a closure is declared, it "captures" the values of variables that it references.
In your case, your closures look something like
{ checkIsSelected in
  if checkIsSelected {
      checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-selected")!
  } else {
      checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
  }
}

There are two variables used in this closure; checkIsSelected, which is the argument passed to the closure, and checkCellView, which is the cell that you want to modify.
Now checkCellView is a property of your view controller.  If we re-write your closure to explicitly add the self. that you omitted when you referred to checkCellView you will see the cause of your problem:
{ checkIsSelected in
  if checkIsSelected {
      self.checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-selected")!
  } else {
      self.checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
  }
}

You thought that because you assigned the closure in your cellForRowAt, the closure would capture the current value of checkCellView, but what is actually captured is self, with self.checkCellView being evaluated when the closure executes.  Since you reassign self.checkCellView each time your diffable data source closure is called, it is unlikely that self.checkCellView actually refers to the desired cell.
One solution would be to use a local variable in your diffable data source closure as you do with your gender cell:
Something like:
    case .indwellingCardiacDeviceOrProsthesis(let bool):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckCellView.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! CheckCellView
        cell.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!         
        cell.switchCheckSelection = { checkIsSelected in
             if checkIsSelected {
                 checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-selected")!
             } else {
                 checkCellView?.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check-box-deselected")!
             }
        }
       return cell

But I would probably change CheckCellView so that it simply had two UImage properties, one for selected and one for de-selected and eliminate the closure all together.  It is just repeated code.

So by eliminating the closure you would execute the logic for setting the image properties in the UITableViewCell?

Exactly. You simply provide the two images (or image names, whichever you prefer) and the logic can just be in your gesture recogniser function.
